# Slider de items (estilo tarjetas): el ítem no se desliza correctamente si tiene elementos hijos, el ítem se desliza con eventos touch

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un slider, en el que se debe deslizar a la izquierda o a la derecha un ítem de un conjunto de items.

Pero tengo problemas al momento de querer tener una imagen y un párrafo como hijos del ítem que quiero deslizar, si deslizo la tarjeta y toco la imagen quien se mueve es la imagen (en este caso se rota) y si toco el párrafo pasa lo mismo. pero el ítem como tal no se mueve.

no puedo usar `z-index` porque el contenedor debe de estar atrás.

Me gustaría que me dijeran que técnica puedo usar para poder mover el ítem sin que sus elementos hijos se vean afectados y el deslizamiento al hacer contacto con todo el elemento ocurra correctamente.

El deslizamiento solo lo tengo para que funcione en pantallas táctiles, no involucro al mouse.

```js
let current_coord_x
let current_coord_y
let has_option_selected = false
let target_middle_width = swipeItem.offsetWidth / 2
let canSlide = false
let degs_count = 0
let targetContainerWidth = swipeContainer.offsetWidth
let marginTopTargets = 5

function getCoords(event) {
  canSlide = true
  if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {
    current_coord_x = event.changedTouches[0].clientX
    current_coord_y = event.changedTouches[0].clientY
  } else {
    current_coord_x = event.clientX
    current_coord_y = event.clientY
  }
  event.preventDefault()
}

function moveTarget(event,target) {

  event.preventDefault()
  let translateX = (event.changedTouches[0].clientX - current_coord_x)
  let translateY = (event.changedTouches[0].clientY - current_coord_y)
  const rotateTarget = function (translateXValue) {

    let rotateValue = translateXValue * 0.10

    if (rotateValue <= -15) {
      target.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + (-15) + "deg)"
    } else if (rotateValue >= 15) {
      target.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + 15 + "deg)"
    } else {
      target.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + rotateValue + "deg)"
    }
  }

  if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {
    target.style.left = translateX + "px"
    target.style.top = translateY + "px"
    rotateTarget(translateX)
  }

}


function calcSelection(target) {

  const coordXfromParent = target.offsetLeft
  const selection = swipeContainer.offsetWidth / 2
  const targetWidth = target.offsetWidth

  if (coordXfromParent >= selection) {
    target.style.color = "green"
    has_option_selected = true
  } else if ((coordXfromParent + targetWidth) <= (targetContainerWidth / 2)) {
    target.style.color = "red"
    has_option_selected = true
  } else {
    target.style.color = "yellow"
    target.style.fontSize = "24px"
    has_option_selected = false
  }
}

function sendTarget(event) {
  canSlide = false
  if (!has_option_selected) {
    event.target.style.transform = "rotateZ(0deg)"
    event.target.style.left = "0"
  } else {
    event.target.style.display = "none"
  }
  event.preventDefault()
}

function slideTarget(e) {
  if (canSlide) {
    moveTarget(e,e.target)
    calcSelection(e.target)
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}

class SwipeSlider {

  constructor(itemsVisibleLenght,swipeItems,swipeContainer) {
    this.items = swipeItems
    this.itemsVisibleLenght = itemsVisibleLenght
    this.container = swipeContainer
  }

  initInteractionWithItems() { 
    let index = 0
    this.items.forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("touchmove", slideTarget, false)
      element.addEventListener("touchstart", getCoords, false)
      element.addEventListener("touchend", sendTarget, false)
      if(index != this.itemsVisibleLenght){
        element.classList.add("visibleTarget")
        element.style.marginTop = marginTopTargets + "px"
        marginTopTargets+=5
      }
      index++
    });
  }


}

let slider = new SwipeSlider(4,document.querySelectorAll(".swipeItem"),document.querySelector("#swipeContainer"))
slider.initInteractionWithItems()
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.swipeImg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.swipeContainer{
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.swipeItem{
  background-color: gainsboro;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1ms;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="selection-zone">
    <article class="swipeContainer" id="swipeContainer">
      <div class="swipeItem" id="swipeItem">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="swipeImg">
        <p id="prospectState">No state yet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swipeItem">
          <img src="2.jpg" class="swipeImg">
        <p id="prospectState">No state yet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swipeItem">
          <img src="3.jpg" class="swipeImg">
        <p id="prospectState">No state yet</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```